# Creating a entity framework SQL table structure

Tags: php, mysql, entity

For the past couple years I've been working on my own lightweight PHP CMS that I use for my personal projects. The one thing its missing is an easy databasing solution.

I am looking to create a simple content type database framework in which I can specify a new type (user, book, event..ect) and then be able to load everything related to it automatically.

For some content types, there could be fields that can only have 1 value and some that can have zero to many values so I will use a new table for these. Take the example:

```
table: event
columns: id, name, description, date

table: event_people:
columns: id_event, id_user

table: event_pictures:
columns: id_event, picture
```

Events will have a bunch of fields that contain a value such as the description, but there could also be a bunch of pictures and people going to it.

I want to be able to create a generic PHP class that will load all the information on a content type. My current thought process is to make entity loader function that I can give it an id and type:

```
Entity:load($id, "event");
```

From this I was going to get all of the tables with the prefix of "event", load all of the data with the passed in ID and then store it in a multidimensional array. I feel like there is probably a more efficient way for this however. I'd like to stay away from having a config file someplace that specifies all of the content types and their child tables because I want to be able to add a new child table and have it pick it up automatically.

Is there anyway to store this relationship directly within the MySQL table? I don't do a lot of databasing and I've just recently started to use foreign keys (what a life saver). Would I be more efficient to see which tables have a foreign key related to the id column in the event table, and if so how would this be done? I'm also open to different ways of storing this information.

Note: I'm doing this just for fun so please don't refer me to use any premade frameworks. I'd like to create this myself.

Comment: You seem to be looking for a  db model. As I see it, PHP shouldn't even be a tag on this thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach of searching for all tables with prefix name event is sensible. The only way I can think to be more efficient is to have an "entity_relationship" table that you could query. It would allow you flexibility in your naming convention, avoid naming conflicts, and this lookup should be more efficient than a pattern match search.

Then whenever a new object type with its own table was added, then you could make an entry on the relationship table.

```
INSERT INTO entity_relationship VALUES 
('event','event_people'),
('event','event_pictures'),
('event','event_documents'),
('event','event_performers');
```